# Website does not allow about half our users to login. Cookies issue. Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-18.04

So to be honest I am not sure how much I can share here. I saw a similar post that was solved on the users end and did not actually lead to a solution on mine. If someone wants the website for testing please let me know or if I can post it here to be simple, I will as well.

So here it goes. I cannot personally replicate the issue, which is making it hard to test and I am out of my depth as is. I have watched others with the issue and this is how we have got this far.

We run a discord community and use Auth from Discord to pull in data from our members and use that for features on the site.

That being said - No roles are the issue here. We have whittled the problem down to a cookie. The website creates a cookie, which goes away during the Auth redirect, then comes back and prevents people from loading the site. Gives a 504 Gateway error. Once I get the users to delete the cookie, they can then load the website again - however they are not logged in.

Have been beating our heads against multiple walls for the past week and we cannot get it down.

I will provide some code here - Hoping this will show some issue, but I imagine it will not. Please let me know if I can provide any more clarity.

```
const r = require('express').Router();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const btoa = require('btoa');
const FormData = require("form-data");
const { catchAsync } = require('./utils/utils.js');
const session = require('express-session');

const redir = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DISCORDCALLBACK)


r.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`https://discord.com/api/v6/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${process.env.CID}&response_type=code&scope=identify%20email`);
});


r.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  if(req.session.accessToken.length > 1) {
      req.session.accessToken = "";
      res.redirect("/");
  } else {
      res.redirect("/");
  }
})


r.get("/callback", catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.code) throw new Error("NoCodeProvided");

  const code = req.query.code;
  //const creds = btoa(`${process.env.CID}:${process.env.SECRET}`);

  const data = new FormData()
  data.append("client_id", process.env.CID);
  data.append("client_secret", process.env.SECRET);
  data.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  data.append("code", code);

  fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v6/oauth2/token`, {
    method: "POST",
    //headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: data
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    fetch("http://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Authorization": `${json.token_type} ${json.access_token}` }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user => {
      req.session.accessToken = `${json.access_token}`
      req.session.cookie.maxAge = 86400000;
      req.session.save(err => {
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        res.redirect("/"); 
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}));



//export route(s)
module.exports = r;
```

Comment: Is the user having a `504` on your website or a discord domain?

Comment: The website. Once they get to the Discord Domain, something in the cookie changes. They can attempt to load the website again all they want, but it will lag out and 504 them. The only way to get back in, let the cookie run it's course and go away or manually remove it.

Comment: Currently checking with the [Discord Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant-authorization-url-example). Your code examples `/authorization` call is not including the necessary `redirect_uri`.

Comment: I am not 100% sure yet and will get back, but I do believe that is calculated and handled in a different way. Would you think that would allow some people in and some not, if it were not correct? 

I will try to come back with how we handle the redirect soon.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys - so I just wanted to update you on what happened. I am thankful for the help and sorry for the waste of time.

One of our programmers said it best: "Lesson learned. Never hardcode values."

For one of Discord's call back for member roles. We had hard coded in a Discord Member ID. This lead to an error and for some reason we still do not understand, half of us being able to get in and half out...

We changed that ID to .env file that we can handle on the Pipeline and boom. People are in.

Thanks for the help!